# How do I obtain the current physical url when url routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

I'm using ASP.NET WebPages (not MVC) to route urls in Application_Start in my Global.asax file.

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable
    .Routes
    .MapWebPageRoute("", "~/Pages/Home.cshtml")
    .MapWebPageRoute("products", "~/Pages/Products.cshtml");
```

How do I obtain the physical url (second parameter given to MapWebPageRoute method) when a request is made?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want to be able to retrieve the .cshtml page url in this context
}
```

I tried Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString() but that only gives me the mapped url.

Comment: You can get the Physical path as follows:
`Request.PhysicalPath`. It will return the physical path.

Comment: @MehulVaghela It still just returns the physical path to the mapped url. I want the url to the .cshtml file

Comment: @AdrianRasca: Okay. I'll try something else and let you know once I found related to this.

Comment: Why do you need that value? Kinda sounds like a flawed design decision incoming...

Comment: @walther I have some custom html parsing in Application_BeginRequest, so I need to know when the page is an .html or .cshtml and not a XHttpRequest or something else.

Comment: I did a PM> Install-Package WebPageRouteHandler but for some reason , I can't access the MapWebPageRoute method even though I see it exists as an extension to RouteCollection... weird.